# Integrate $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{{1}}{(a^2+x^2)^7}\,dx\\$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{{1}}{(a^2+x^2)^7}\,dx\\$$
tried with $x = a\tan(y)$.

Comment: Welcome to the MSE community! Could you please show your own efforts at trying to solve it?

Comment: x=atan(y) 
dx=asec^2(y)
integral changes to 0 to pi/2 1/a^13 * cos^12y

Comment: Looks about right, now you have a very annoying but also rather straightforward trigonometric integral to do. (This is of course assuming that you don't know anything about residue calculus. If you do then you can use that to take a shortcut.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a more general case,let $$I_n=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{{1}}{(a^2+x^2)^n}dx$$Using partial integration, we have$$I_n=\frac{x}{(a^2+x^2)^n}\bigg|_{0}^{+\infty}+2n\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{{x^2}}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx=2n\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{{a^2+x^2-a^2}}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx=2nI_n-2na^2I_{n+1}$$We got it$$2na^2I_{n+1}=(2n-1)I_n,(2n-2)a^2I_n=(2n-3)I_{n-1}$$
So$$I_n=\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdots\frac{1}{2}\cdot I_1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdots\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}$$

Thus$$I_n=\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdots\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\varepsilon$$
Among$$\varepsilon=\begin{cases}
1,&a>0\\
-1,&a<0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: can you confirm my solution above in comments is correct or wrong?

Comment: @111111 First，the sign of the final result depends on $a$.Then,I'm sorry your result is not correct.You can compare the results I gave you.If my answer is helpful to you, please press Accepted

Comment: thanks for help got the correct ans did a silly mistake in calculation